# why doesn't my c# base constructor get called?

Tags: c#

```
public class Animal
{
    public Animal()
    {
        "animal ctor".Dump();
    }
}

public class Cat :Animal
{
    public Cat():this("gray")
    {
        "cat ctor".Dump();
    }

    public Cat(string c):base()
    {
        "cat ctor2".Dump();
    }
}

void Main()
{
    Cat a = new Cat();
}
```

The code's output is :

```
animal ctor
cat ctor2
cat ctor
```

I understand the first line.

The Animal Ctor is called first, but then the Cat ctor is calling the string overload `public Cat(string c):base()` - but this ALSO calls base's constructor.

So why I don't see `animal ctor` again (`:base()`)?

Comment: The animal ctor is called once, from the `Cat(string)` constructor, before the body of that constructor runs.  That's why its output appears first.

Comment: Since the `base` is automatically called, using `:base()` is redundant (tools like Resharper tell you to remove it)

Comment: Are you confusing `: this()` with `: base()`?

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips no I'm testing

Comment: Why do you expect any constructor to be called more than once when constructing an object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the constructor is only called once:

1. your `Cat()` constructor calls `Cat(string c)`
2. `Cat(string c)` is calling *base* constructor
3. base constructor is executed
4. `Cat(string c)` is executed (which is the caller of base)
5. Then `Cat()` constructor is executed

Basically if you call the *base* constructor (or another constructor in your class), that is executed before your constructor.See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx) for more details

Comment: What if i remove the `:base()` ? then who calls the animal ctor ?\

Comment: @d11 Per [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24413267/50447), the compiler adds the implicit call to the default constructor for the base class if (and only if) you don't tell it which constructor to call

Answer (score 1):

`Cat()` explicitly calls `Cat(string)` which explicitly calls `Animal()`.

These calls happen *before* each method starts, so you see them dumped in reverse order.

`Cat()` does not call `Animal()` directly, meaning the base class' constructor would only be called once (which, is probably what you want)

If you don't explicitly specify which constructor to call, then the default constructor for the base class is called; So the following:

```
public Cat(string c) :base()
{
    "cat ctor2".Dump();
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
public Cat(string c)
{
    "cat ctor2".Dump();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few rules of inheritance and object construction.

Here, the constructor is called in sequence Cat() : this(string) which is Cat(string) : base() which is Animal()

Animal is base of Cat so Animal is constructed first. once Animal() constructor call is finished, then Cat(string) will complete and subsequently Cat() invocation will be completed.

Even if you do not mention base(), base will still be invoked. A parameterless constructor is always invoked by default (if available) and this process is bubbled up to the topmost parent in hierarchy.

A parameterless constructor is always present for every class. But, if you declare one with a parameter, then you explicitly need to declare a parameterless constructor.